# Gradle Exec task with variables not working

Tags: gradle

I am trying to pass the variables from other tasks to Exec task and use them as arguments as below. But, gradle variables are not being de-referenced in "args" variable of the Exec task "sideloadOraDb".

//the variable is defined within script root
    def String tenant
    def String instance

```
task getInstance(type:Exec){
   workingDir System.getenv('T_WORK')
   commandLine 'echo'
   args 'abc'
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  doLast{
      instance = standardOutput.toString().trim()
      print instance
  }
}

task getTenant(type:Exec,dependsOn:getInstance){
   workingDir System.getenv('T_WORK')
   commandLine 'echo'
   args 'xyz'
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  doLast{
      tenant = standardOutput.toString().trim()
      print tenant
  }
}

task sideloadOraDb(type:Exec,dependsOn:getTenant){
   def String cmd

   doFirst{
        println "Instacne="+instance
        println "Tenant="+tenant
   }
   commandLine 'echo'
   args tenant,instance

}
```

Output

```
bash-4.1$ vi build.gradle 
bash-4.1$ gradle sideloadOraDb
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:getInstance
abc:getTenant
xyz:sideloadOraDb
Instacne=abc
Tenant=xyz

:sideloadOraDb FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sideloadOraDb'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I tried with placing variables into command directly, but it is also not helping :-

```
task sideloadOraDb(type:Exec,dependsOn:getTenant){
   def String cmd

   doFirst{
        println "Instacne="+instance
        println "Tenant="+tenant
   }
   commandLine 'echo',tenant,instance
//   args tenant,instance

}
```

output

```
bash-4.1$ gradle sideloadOraDb
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:getInstance
abc:getTenant
xyz:sideloadOraDb
Instacne=abc
Tenant=xyz
:sideloadOraDb FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sideloadOraDb'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.326 secs
bash-4.1$
```

Can you please let me know, whats going over here ?

Comment: Try moving `args tenant, instance` into the `doFirst { }` block. Your problem is that `args` in its current position is run during Gradle's evaluation phase and not its execution phase.

Comment: It works !!! Thanks a ton. Why is not working outside of doFirst ?

Comment: It's all about the build lifecycle of Gradle. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html Outside is evaluated during the configuration phase. Inside the doFirst, it's the execution phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution from @nickb :-

```
//the variable is defined within script root
def String tenant
def String instance

task getInstance(type:Exec){
   workingDir System.getenv('T_WORK')
   commandLine 'echo'
   args 'abc'
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  doLast{
      instance = standardOutput.toString().trim()
      print instance
  }
}

task getTenant(type:Exec,dependsOn:getInstance){
   workingDir System.getenv('T_WORK')
   commandLine 'echo'
   args 'xyz'
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  doLast{
      tenant = standardOutput.toString().trim()
      print tenant
  }
}

task sideloadOraDb(type:Exec,dependsOn:getTenant){
   def String cmd

   doFirst{
        println "Instacne="+instance
        println "Tenant="+tenant
        args tenant,instance
   }
   commandLine 'echo'
}
```

Output

```
bash-4.1$ gradle sideloadOraDb
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:getInstance
abc:getTenant
xyz:sideloadOraDb
Instacne=abc
Tenant=xyz
xyz abc

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: any chance you know why on linux sometimes the arguments count is always zero? seem I can't really never pass variables on my jenkins worker node